# attach the path of each element in a tree

Tags: haskell, tree

Consider the following tree data structure:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving Show
```

and a function which attaches to each element its path in the tree:

```
withPath :: Tree a -> Tree (a, [a])
withPath t = go [] t where
  go path (Node v xs) = Node (v, p) (map (go p) xs) where
    p = path ++ [v]

withPath (Node 4 [Node 3 [], Node 5 []])
--> Node (4,[4]) [Node (3,[4,3]) [],Node (5,[4,5]) []]
```

Is this the way to do it? I'm looking for a way to avoid the construction of the path by concatenation.

---

here is a solution proposed by jberryman.

```
withPath' :: Tree a -> Tree (a, [a])
withPath' t = go id t where
  go f (Node v xs) = Node (v, f' []) (map (go f') xs) where
    f' = f . (v:)
```

Comment: Look at DList, or simply compose and pass an equivalent function as you move down the tree (like `(a :) . (b :) . (c :)`)

Comment: interesting approach, I added an implementation to the end of the post.

Comment: Very nice. The following is obviously a very simple comment, but it illustrates your idea, and it tickled me. Here is a version of reverse using `foldr`. `reverse xs = foldr (\x f -> f . (x:)) id xs $ []`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another (not necessarily simpler) way to do it, using a recursion scheme called a *catamorphism*. `Data.Tree` in the latest version of *containers* has the [function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Tree.html#v:foldTree):

> foldTree :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b

Which is a catamorphism on trees (compared to `foldr`, which is the catamorphism for lists). Given an auxiliary function, it "destroys" the tree starting from the leaves and going upwards to the root.

However, we actually want to go the other way: we want to start at the root and propagate the path information to each subtree.

Turns out that there is a trick for doing this using a catamorphism: instead of making the catamorphism return the path-annotated tree directly, *make it return a function* that takes a root path and returns the path-annotated tree. Something like:

```
import Data.Tree
import Data.List.NonEmpty

inherit :: Tree a -> Tree (NonEmpty a)
inherit tree = foldTree algebra tree [] where
    algebra :: a -> [[a] -> Tree (NonEmpty a)] -> [a] -> Tree (NonEmpty a)
    algebra a fs as = Node (a:|as) (fs <*> [a:as])
```

Here, the result of the catamorphism is of type `[a] -> Tree (NonEmpty a)`. `inherit` supplies the initial empty path.

A simpler version of this trick is [expressing foldl in terms of foldr](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr) (if you squint a little, the first element of a list is like the “root” of a linear tree). A beefed-up version of this trick allows [calculating inherited attributes in attribute grammars](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~jeuri101/homepage/Publications/ags.pdf).

The idea that being able to return functions form a catamorphism increases its expressive power is explained in section 5 of the paper ["A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold"](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf).

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? `fs <*> [a:as]` is either a singleton list (if `fs` has at least one element) or is empty (if `fs` is empty) - this cannot produce a tree with the shape of the original tree.

Comment: @user2407038 `(<*>)` for lists takes all posible combinations; since `[a:as]` has one element, `fs <*> [a:as]` has the same number of elements as `fs`.

Comment: looks like a very promising approach. I still have the impression that the paths are in the wrong order when trying this out with some data. Am I missing something here? Is the NonEmpty part necessary here?

Comment: @AntonHarald Yes, the paths start from the current node. You will have to `fmap reverse` the tree if you want them to start at the root. The `NonEmpty` is not really necessary, I just find it more readable than `(a,[a])`.